# Large Deviations for $\nu_\epsilon = Z_\epsilon\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Phi(x)\right)d\mu$

Tags: pr.probability

Given a probability measure of the form 
$$\nu_\epsilon=Z_\epsilon\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Phi(x)\right)d\mu$$
with $Z$ being the normalizing constant.

Under which  conditions on $\mu$ and $\Phi$ does $\nu_\epsilon$ satisfies a large deviation principle or concentrate around the minimas of $\Phi$.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Look up Varadhan's lemma in any large deviations text. Specifically, Deuschel-Stroock, Exercise 2.1.24